# php function and mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a real beginner with php and I really need help. Here is my code for my first file where I need to call an insertnewmarker function from my second file.

I really dont know how and where to call the function. (the code of the second file is below) I need to insert `$name` in database

1st file code:

```
require_once('includes/php.config.db.php');

function curl($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
}

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.kupime.com/aktivne-ponude/'); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$entries = $xpath->query("//ul[@id='list_offers']//table//a/@href");
$output = array(); 
$i = 1;
foreach($entries as $e) {   
  $dom2 = new DOMDocument(); 
  @$dom2->loadHTMLFile('http://www.kupime.com' . $e->textContent); 
  $xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2); 
  $data = array();
  $data['link']= ('http://www.kupime.com' . $e->textContent);
  $data['naslov'] = trim($xpath2->query("//h1[@id='offer_title']")->item(0)->textContent); 
  $data['opis'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@id='company_info']")->item(0)->textContent); 
  $data['slika'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@id='img_border']/img/@src")->item(0)->textContent); 
  $location = $xpath2->query("//div[@id='location']//script")->item(1)->textContent; 
  preg_match('/var\s+lat\s+=\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*;/', $location, $lat); 
  preg_match('/var\s+lang\s+=\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*;/', $location, $lng); 
  $data['lat'] = $lat[1]; 
  $data['lng'] = $lng[1]; 
  $data['popust'] = trim($xpath2->query("//li[@class='discount']")->item(0)->textContent);
  $data['firma'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@id='company_info']/h3")->item(0)->textContent); 
  $data['telefon'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@id='company_info']/p[2]")->item(0)->textContent);
  $data['email'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@id='company_info']/p[3]/a[1]/@href")->item(0)->textContent);
  $data['sajt'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@id='company_info']/p[3]/a[2]/@href")->item(0)->textContent);

//vreme
    $data['sat'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@class='countdown hasCountdown']/strong[1]")->item(0)->textContent); 
    $data['minut'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@class='countdown hasCountdown']/strong[2]")->item(0)->textContent); 
    $data['sekund'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@class='countdown hasCountdown']/strong[3]")->item(0)->textContent); 


    $data['vreme'] = time() + $data['sekund']+ $data['minut']*60 + $data['sat']*3600;

$image_url = 'http://www.kupime.com'.$data['slika']; 

  $naslov = $data['naslov'];
  $latitude = $data['lat'];
  $longitude = $data['lng'];
  $latitude = (float) $latitude;
  $lin = $data['link'];
  $vreme = $data['vreme'];

  $popust = str_replace ('POPUST','',$data['popust']);
  $firma = $data['firma']; 
  $telefon = $data['telefon'];
  $email = $data['email'];
  $sajt = $data['sajt'];
  $type = 'bar';

  $latitude = (float) $latitude;
  $longitude = (float) $longitude;

  $output[] = $data; 
} 





?>
</body>
</html>
```

Second file code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(true);
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('<p>Connection imposible!</p>');

mysql_select_db('tablename', $link);

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_general_ci'");



function insertNewMarker($name='', $lat='', $lng='', $slika='', $link='', $type='', $popust='', $vaziDo='') {

    if(!empty($name) and !empty($lat) and !empty($lng) and !empty($link)) {

        $name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($name));



        $sql = "INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `lat`, `lng`, `address`, `totolink`, `type`, `popust`, `vaziDo`) VALUES ('$name', '$lat', '$lng', '$slika', '$link', '$type', '$popust', '$vaziDo')";

        mysql_query($sql) or print "<p>Error in SQL Statement ($sql):<br />". mysql_error() .'</p>';

    }

    else {

        print "<p>Polja 'name', 'lat' i 'lng' can't be empty!<br />Vi ste uneli <br />Name:$name<br />Lat:$lat<br />Lng:$lng</p>";

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: What is your question? You want to call the function from inside the first file?

Comment: yes, but i dont know how and where to call function insertnewmarker from second file

Comment: Which file are you trying to call it from? One or two?

Comment: I try to call second file where is my code for insert into database (function insertnewmarker) in first file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[1 file] after:

```
$longitude = (float) $longitude;
```

[1 file] add:

```
include('second_file.php');
insertNewMarker($name, $lat, $lng, $slika, $link, $type, $popust, $vaziDo);
```

and make sure function arguments `$name, $lat, $lng, $slika, $link, $type, $popust, $vaziDo` are assigned - i can't help you in this, cause i dont understand your language, anyways it's your job :)

Comment: i think that include is not need becouse i have requie_once on first line